# Collectibles not appearing in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As I've ditched using Phaser, I've gotten more work done to the point of the sprite moving, and I finished programming the collision detection, but I need something more... I decided to make coins to collect for a currency. I tried programming them to appear at random points on the map using a randomRange function. I managed to get one coin spawn in the upper left corner of the canvas, but I made one slight change, and the coin just stopped spawning in the canvas at all. I've called the coins under the function collectibles, which I've called upon in the update and draw functions. Just adding them to the update and draw functions made my player sprite be locked in place! Do I need a JS library just to make the coins spawn?

Here's the code:

```
function collectibles () {
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.width = 20; //how wide the sprite is in pixels
    this.height = 20; //how tall the sprite is in pixels
    this.drawX = this.randomRange;
    this.drawY = this.randomRange;
    this.centerX = this.drawX + (this.width / 2);
    this.centerY = this.drawY + (this.height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any errors in console? If 'randomRange' is a function it lacks braces() at the end where you call it. 'this' might differ depending on where you call the function 'collectibles'.

Comment: I tried using the braces() at the end for 'randomRange', but when I did that, it made my game crash. I was confused as to why.

Comment: It might be because 'this' has not the function 'randomRange' and you have an error in console. And before placing braces you had 'undefined' for properties 'drawX' and 'drawY'.  You can debug and see what is 'this' by placing breakpoint  inside  your 'collectibles' function. Or you can write inside your 'collectibles' function console.log('this', this); Then open console and see what it gives. You can learn about opening and using console here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console